# Changing input type from file to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My requirement is initially my input type should be "file" but its read only. So along with choose file I should be able to write the file name in the textbox.
Can anyone help? I should write the file name like writing text in textbox.

Comment: I can't understand your purpose. Please explain more about your purpose and what you want. Also add code if you have it.

Comment: you mean you have an up-loader that you don't want user to be able to choose files but just write names of files?

Comment: Actually in file input we can only choose files by clicking on Choose file button, and if we wont select any file there will be comment "No file choosen", in that palce I can edit the text like I can type my file name instead of choosing file. Two functionalities should be there Choosing file by clicking on choose file button and by typing file name.

Comment: <input type="file"/>  I can only upload files after selecting a file the file name will populate in place of "No file choosen". So My requirement is I should be able to edit the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var change = document.getElementById("change");

    //Do whatever then call when you need it
$('#changer').click(function(){
  change.type = 'text';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="change">
<br>
<button type="button" id="changer">Change Type</button>
```

Comment: Actually in file input we can only choose files by clicking on Choose file button, and if we wont select any file there will be comment "No file choosen", in that palce I can edit the text like I can type my file name instead of choosing file. Two functionalities should be there Choosing file by clicking on choose file button and by typing file name.    While page loading itself it should come with these two functionalities. Whatever u sent after clicking on change type I can edit

Comment: there is no way for you to change that text your only other option is to just add another text field beside the file input

Comment: in file type also it will come as textbox right? and it is read only. Is there any way to make it as editable box

Comment: I dont understand what your asking

Comment: <input type="file"/>  I can only upload files after selecting a file the file name will populate in place of "No file choosen". So My requirement is I should be able to edit the file name.

Comment: A simple google search could have answered your questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560907/html5-file-api-modify-file-name

Comment: Not only editing the file name but also directly I should be able copy the file name to that textbox instead of selecting it

Comment: It seems its not possible to make file input as editable

Comment: if i helped please reember to click the chdckmark next to my answer

Comment: Do u knw is there any way to implement those functionalities as I said?